# How can I draw a nonlinear spring in the style of Circuitikz for a mechanical schematic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

The circuitikz package provides an easy way to draw linear springs (springs that have constant stiffness) in a mechanical circuit. I would like to draw a nonlinear spring (its stiffness varies as it stretches) in a circuitikz-like manner, but circuitikz does not provide a symbol for a nonlinear spring. How can I do this?

### Desired output

I would like the symbol to look like a spring with unevenly spaced coils:

[image: the desired nonlinear spring symbol]

### Minimal working example

This code will generate a linear spring symbol.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [spring] (0, 2);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of minimal working example code]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made a less clumsy version, in which you can use a key `factor` to set how off the spring is of the center and, in the process, I ended up making things easy to change the number of coils in the spring, so I added a `coils` key to change that as well. The default value for `factor` is `0`, so that the behaviour is the same of the original `spring`, and the default for `coils` is `4`, the same as the original.

Now you can use it with:

```
\draw (0,0) to [ravenspring={factor=2,coils=4}] (0, 2);
```

without changing any definition.

The old answer is down below, for reference.

> [image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__raven_factor:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
  { \fp_eval:n { #2 + #1*(#3 - (#2))/#4 } }
\cs_new:Npn \__raven_factor_half:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
  { \fp_eval:n { 0.5 * ( #2 + #1*(#3 - #2)/#4 ) } }
\cs_set_eq:NN \FullFactor \__raven_factor:nnnn
\cs_set_eq:NN \HalfFactor \__raven_factor_half:nnnn
\cs_set_eq:NN \IntStepVariable \int_step_variable:nnNn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\ctikzset{bipoles/ravenspring/height/.initial=.5}
\ctikzset{bipoles/ravenspring/width/.initial=.5}
\ctikzset{bipoles/ravenspring/factor/.initial=0}
\ctikzset{bipoles/ravenspring/coils/.initial=4}
\def\pgf@circ@ravenspring@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{ravenspring}{#1}}
\compattikzset{%
  ravenspring/.code = {%
    \ctikzset{\circuitikzbasekey,/tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@ravenspring@path}%
    \ctikzset{\circuitikzbasekey/bipoles/ravenspring/.cd,#1}
  }
}

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ravenspring/height}}
  {ravenspring}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ravenspring/height}}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ravenspring/width}}
  {%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgftransformationadjustments

    \edef\raven@coils{\number\numexpr\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ravenspring/coils}*2+1}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@res@step}
    {(\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ravenspring/width}*\pgf@circ@Rlen+\pgfhorizontaltransformationadjustment*.5*\pgflinewidth)/(\raven@coils-1)/2}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left-\pgfhorizontaltransformationadjustment*0.5*\pgflinewidth}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgf@circ@res@other = \pgf@circ@res@left
    \edef\raven@factor{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ravenspring/factor}}
    \IntStepVariable {1} {\raven@coils} \raven@coil
      {%
        \advance\pgf@circ@res@other by
        \ifnum
          \ifnum\raven@coil=1\space 1\else 0\fi
          \ifnum\raven@coil=\raven@coils\space 1\else 0\fi
          =0
          \expandafter\FullFactor
        \else
          \expandafter\HalfFactor
        \fi
          {\raven@coil}{2-\raven@factor}{2+\raven@factor}{\raven@coils}\pgf@circ@res@step
        \ifnum \raven@coil=\raven@coils
          \let\raven@moveto\pgf@circ@res@zero
        \else
          \ifodd\raven@coil
            \let\raven@moveto\pgf@circ@res@up
          \else
            \let\raven@moveto\pgf@circ@res@down
          \fi
        \fi
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\raven@moveto}}
      }
    \pgfsetbuttcap
    \pgfsetbeveljoin
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [ravenspring={factor=2,coils=4}] (0, 2);
  \end{circuitikz}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [ravenspring={factor=3,coils=6}] (0, 2);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

---

Old answer, setting factors manually:

I declared a new shape, `ravenspring` (if you want to rename it just change all occurrences of `ravespring` to whatever name you prefer):

> [image]

To change the ratio between each loop of the spring you have to change the `<factor>` in:

```
\advance\pgf@circ@res@other by <factor>\pgf@circ@res@step
```

so that the sum of the factors is `16`. If you don't get the sum to be `16`, then the spring will be shorter or longer than the gap available. Furthermore, the first and last factors should be halved, otherwise the last half coil of the spring will be too long.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\ctikzset{bipoles/ravenspring/height/.initial=.5}
\ctikzset{bipoles/ravenspring/width/.initial=.5}
\def\pgf@circ@ravenspring@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{ravenspring}{#1}}
\compattikzset{ravenspring/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@ravenspring@path, l=#1}}
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ravenspring/height}}
  {ravenspring}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ravenspring/height}}
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ravenspring/width}}
  {%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgftransformationadjustments

    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@res@step}
    {(\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ravenspring/width}*\pgf@circ@Rlen+\pgfhorizontaltransformationadjustment*.5*\pgflinewidth)/16}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left-\pgfhorizontaltransformationadjustment*0.5*\pgflinewidth}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgf@circ@res@other = \pgf@circ@res@left
    \advance\pgf@circ@res@other by 0.50\pgf@circ@res@step
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \advance\pgf@circ@res@other by 1.25\pgf@circ@res@step 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \advance\pgf@circ@res@other by 1.50\pgf@circ@res@step
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \advance\pgf@circ@res@other by 1.75\pgf@circ@res@step
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \advance\pgf@circ@res@other by 2.00\pgf@circ@res@step
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \advance\pgf@circ@res@other by 2.25\pgf@circ@res@step
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \advance\pgf@circ@res@other by 2.50\pgf@circ@res@step
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \advance\pgf@circ@res@other by 2.75\pgf@circ@res@step
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \advance\pgf@circ@res@other by 1.50\pgf@circ@res@step
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfsetbuttcap
    \pgfsetbeveljoin
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [ravenspring] (0, 2);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

---

A few variants, changing the *unevenness* of the spring:

The one above:

> [image]

`<factor>`s:

```
0.500
1.250
1.500
1.750
2.000
2.250
2.500
2.750
1.500
```

More distorted:

> [image]

`<factor>`s:

```
0.250
0.875
1.250
1.625
2.000
2.375
2.750
3.125
1.750
```

Less distorted:

> [image]

`<factor>`s:

```
0.750
1.625
1.750
1.875
2.000
2.125
2.250
2.375
1.250
```

Broken:

> [image]

`<factor>`s:

```
0.000
0.500
1.000
1.500
2.000
2.500
3.000
3.500
2.000
```

Comment: Impressive positively. My true compliments.